# Stanley kinematic model controller

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, kinematics

I am having problem calculating delta (steering angle).

L is the length of vehicle lfw is distance between rear and center of vehicle.

eta is the angle between direction of the vehicle and target on the path (blue line).

Lfw is the look ahead distance (how far vehicle is looking to find a a point to set as target)

R` is the curve radius.

Finally I need to obtain delta as function of Lfw, lfw, eta:

delta = -tan^-1(L.sin(eta)/(Lfw/2+lfw.cos(eta))

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is actually just trigonometry. You just have to write three equations and some simple manipulation will give you the answer. First one can write 
$$\tan(90-\delta)=R/L$$
This implies 
$$\tan(\delta)=L/R$$
Let's say that the length joining the centre of the path to the midpoint of the vehicle is $d$ and the angle made by $d$ and $l_{fw}$ is $\theta$. Hence the second equation is
$$\tan(\theta)=R/l_{fw}$$
The third equation can be written using the angle made by $d$ and $L_{fw}$. This angle will be $180-\eta-\theta$. By making a perpendicular from the centre to the mid point of $L_{fw}$ one can write 
$$-\cos(\eta+\theta)=\frac{L_{fw}}{2d}$$
By manipulating the above equation and using $R=d\sin(\theta)$, $R$ can be found in terms of $L_{fw}$,$l_{fw}$ and $\eta$. That can be substituted in the first equation to get the desired result. Expanding the above equation
$$-\cos(\eta)\cos(\theta)+\sin(\eta)\sin(\theta)=\frac{L_{fw}\sin(\theta)}{2R}$$
Dividing by $\sin(\theta)$ on both sides and substituting $\cot(\theta)$ using equation (2), we obtain
$$\frac{L_{fw}}{2R}= -\frac{l_{fw}}{R} +sin(\eta)$$
Solving for $R$
$$R=\frac{L_{fw}+2l_{fw}\cos(\eta)}{2\sin(\eta)}$$
Substituting this in the first equation,
$$tan(\delta)= \frac{L\sin(\eta)}{\frac{L_{fw}}{2}+l_{fw}\cos(\eta)}$$

Comment: Thanks for the help, but: `By making a perpendicular from the centre to the mid point of Lfw one can write` I think in this case you are fixing `lfw to be Lfw/2` isn't it?

Comment: @eggrobot78 To get the answer you'll have to expand $\cos(\theta+\eta)$ in the third equation. Then you'll have to divide both sides by $\sin(\theta)$.

Comment: @eggrobot78 No. When I draw a perpendicular from the centre to $L_{wf}$ (which is clearly a chord) will be divided into two parts each of length $L_{wf}/2$ (properties of chords of circles). I have never used $L_{wf}/2=l_{wf}$.

Comment: I think it's going on the right way, will it be possible to eliminate `sin(θ)` in the final equation?

Comment: tg(δ)=(-2.L.[cos^2⁡θ-sin^2⁡〖(η)]〗)/(L_fw.sin⁡(θ) )

Comment: @eggrobot78 I have included a complete derivation in my answer.

Comment: One thing I didn't understand is the `tg(δ) = -L/R` isn't it suppose to be L/R? The bigger triangle is composed by δ, 90-δ and 90 degree angles

Comment: @eggrobot78 yes, you are right about that. I'll edit my answer.

Comment: Paper's answer is negative and in our case positive. When solving got positive too, I am trying to find where the mistake is.

Comment: I think there is a mistake in the paper, my friend got also positive.